# Is it possible drawing on top of an uploaded image

Tags: c++-cli, picturebox

I am working with a CLR Windows Forms App. I upload an image that I want to use as a template and then draw on top of it depending on same values. 
However, what I draw appears below the image. This is how I am drawing:

```
PictureBox ^g = gcnew PictureBox;
g->Parent = this;
g->Location = Point(630,20);
g->Size::set(Drawing::Size(900,90));
g->BackColor::set(Color::Aquamarine);
```

So the question is if anybody knows how to draw on top of the image.

Comment: You don't assign the Image property, you don't use the Paint event.  Impossible to guess what you are doing wrong.  Improve your snippet.

Comment: Have you tried drawing on the image itself, rather than on a PictureBox?